# Libreoffice broke after updating to Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: libreoffice, 21.10

When I first updated to Ubuntu 21.10, LibreOffice just stopped working. However, I found out that some java dependencies where missing. After downloading them, LibreOffice worked again. The only problem is... It takes over 5 minutes to open anything (even a blank document), but after some research I found this:

https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/libre-office-is-slow/1789

The only problem is that it seems like that does not appear anymore on the version I have.

I already tried purging LibreOffice and reinstalling, and doing the same from Ubuntu Software

Some additional info:
I have been using Ubuntu since 20.04 on this machine. I never had problems before.
I also have an Nvidia graphics card.

**EDIT:**
As requested, the output of:

```
snap list | grep -i libreoffice; flatpak list | grep -i libreoffice; apt-cache policy libreoffice; lowriter --version
```

is

```
Command 'flatpak' not found, but can be installed with:
```

So I tried it without the flatpack part:

```
lowriter --version
libreoffice:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:7.2.2-0ubuntu0.21.10.1
  Version table:
     1:7.2.2-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 500 (phased 10%)
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     1:7.2.1-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe amd64 Packages
LibreOffice 7.2.2.2 20(Build:2)
```

As to how I updated, I updated from Ubuntu 21.04, through the command line by doing `sudo distr-update` There where no problems during the update.

I did `sudo apt purge LibreOffice` once I updated, because it seemed it didn't work and I couldn't find anything wrong. I installed afterwards from the snap store (ubuntu software) on the 21.10 channel.

To fix the problem, I installed this:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre libreoffice-java-common
```

Comment: please [edit] your question with further details - how you did the upgrade to 20.10 and from which version and what you did you "purge" LO including the instructions you used to do so and finally what you did to reinstall LO. A vanilla installation of 21.10 includes LO and works well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to run a full (re)installation of LibreOffice using deb-packages from official Ubuntu repositories by using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libreoffice
```

As a final remediation you can clear its config folder by

```
rm -rfv ~/.config/libreoffice
```

Comment: Did it, still takes a lot of time to run.

Comment: `rm -rfv ~/.config/libreoffice` Worked perfectly! I guess that was all... Thanks a lot for your help.