# LibreOffice Writer - All Documents (Old and New) Are Blank

Tags: libreoffice

Today I opened LibreOffice Writer for the first time in 2 weeks +/-.  I find that all of the  documents that I saved previously (odt format) are blank, i.e. when I open any previously saved document I get a single blank page and on the status bar it says "0 words, 0 characters".

If I create a new document, enter some text, save the document, close write, start write, reopen the document - same thing, the document is blank as described above.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit**: I tried deleting my profile as described here: [Resolving corruption](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/UserProfile#Resolving_corruption), that did not help.

**Edit #2**:

@Bodo:

> Can you create a file with contents using a command (echo test > test.txt) or a different program, e.g. gedit?

Yes.  Furthermore if I examine the contents of the odt files I can see that they are not empty.

@N0rbert:

> Does this answer your question? [Libreoffice broke after updating to Ubuntu 21.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371747/libreoffice-broke-after-updating-to-ubuntu-21-10)

I tried reinstalling libreoffice and clearing my config folder as per your response to that issue, it did not fix the problem unfortunately.  I am on ubuntu 20.04.  There was a big update a couple days ago and I strongly suspect that that is the cause of the problem.

**Edit #3**: I installed abiword and with that I am able to edit my odt files as normal.

**Edit #4**: As requested in the comments by N0rbert:

```
erik@laptop2:~$ which lowriter
/usr/bin/lowriter
erik@laptop2:~$ apt-cache policy libreoffice
libreoffice:
  Installed: 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
  Candidate: 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
erik@laptop2:~$ snap list | grep -i libreoffice
erik@laptop2:~$ flatpak list | grep -i libreoffice

Command 'flatpak' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install flatpak
```

Comment: Can you create a file with contents using a command (`echo test > test.txt`) or a different program, e.g. `gedit`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Libreoffice broke after updating to Ubuntu 21.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371747/libreoffice-broke-after-updating-to-ubuntu-21-10)

Comment: >Bodo yes >N0rbert checking

Comment: @eric. Could you please elaborate how LO is installed? From Snap, Flatpak, deb?

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me.  LibreOffice came bundled with Ubuntu 20.04 and I believe it's managed under apt and not snap.  I don't understand very well how the various package managers interact.

Comment: It would be great if you add output of `which lowriter`, `apt-cache policy libreoffice`, `snap list | grep -i libreoffice`, `flatpak list | grep -i libreoffice` to the question.

Comment: Output added to OP as requested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131900/discussion-between-n0rbert-and-eric).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem by installing abiword which allowed me to reacquire access to all my old odt files