# LibreOffice Calc in Ubuntu 22.04 runs very slowly!

Tags: updates, libreoffice, 22.04

I've recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS desktop version. Now, LibreOffice Calc runs slowly. Every time I highlight a cell and start typing, the UI catches up after about 1 sec. Selecting a cell and dragging to select multiple cells falls behind building the selection and only catches up after about 2 secs. Using CTRL-F and entering a text string to find a cell makes me wait for a sec otherwise it loses the first few keystrokes I enter. The cumulative effect of all of these delays makes Calc almost unusable on Ubuntu 22.04.

I am running:
Micro-Star GF75 Thin (10SCSR) laptop
Intel Core i5-10300H CPU
16GB RAM (2,667 MT/sec)
GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile Graphics Card
DisplayLink 4K video dock (driver ver. 5.5.0)
Twin 4K displays (dock connected)

Comment: fyi the displaylink dock has its own drivers for GUI and ignore the nVidia card when it comes to GUI.  I've seen this slowness before in non-22.04 when relying only on the displaylinks in an external dock, and determined it is the displaylink drivers being slow and non-performance unlike the nvidia card and on-system adapters.  Jist my 2 cents but it might be a limitation of DisplayLink.

Comment: TY for pointing this out. If the DisplayLink driver does not use the nVidia card to render the image on the monitors, where does the driver do this processing? In the CPU itself? In the alternate Intel CometLake-H video card on the laptop's mobo? Is there a way to check where the DisplayLink driver does its processing?

Comment: i dont know enough about the driver to answer but I would assume the DisplayLink devices themselves render the image.  Either that or your CPU.  I am not an expert at the displaylink drivers but I do know from testing they dont use the onboard GPU of your computer.

Comment: The answers given in the following tread worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371747/libreoffice-broke-after-updating-to-ubuntu-21-10